# Currency denomination

Tags: c++, string, parsing

Trying to use proper currency denomination for my game.  The currency is stored as a string (i.e. can't change that due to my professor) and is in the order of Platinum, Gold, Silver and Copper.  For example, I if I initialize my currency to "0.1.23.15" this means I have 0 Platinum, 1 Gold, 23 Silver and 15 Copper.

I need to be able to covert to a higher denomination, however.  What does that mean?  An example would be if I have 105 silver pieces (i.e. 0.0.105.0), it should show up as 1 gold and 5 silver (i.e. 0.1.5.0).

I bolded my problem within my setCost method.  I am checking if a number greater than 100 and if it is -- I make that column 0, go back to the previous element and add one to the ASCII value giving a proper carry.  Unfortunately, the debugger is showing "/x4" is being dumped into the element instead of just "4".  Does anyone know why this is and how I can change it??

**EDIT: Edited the code and it works as long as you don't enter a number above 100.  Having a brain lapse on how to make it work for numbers larger than 100.**

This is some of the sloppiest code I have ever written.  Please be gentle. :(

```
void Potion::setCost(std::string cost)
{
    char buffer[256];
    std::string currencyBuffer [4];
    int integerBuffer[4];
    int * integerPointer = nullptr;
    int temp = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char * tokenPtr;
    //Convert string to cString
    strcpy(buffer, cost.c_str() );

    //Tokenize cString
    tokenPtr = strtok(buffer, ".");

    while(tokenPtr != nullptr)
    {
        //Convert ASCII to integer
        temp = atoi(tokenPtr);

        //Store temp into currency buffer
        integerBuffer[i] = temp;

        //Make pointer point to integer buffer
        integerPointer = &integerBuffer[i];

        if(*integerPointer < 100)
            currencyBuffer[i] = tokenPtr;
        else
        {
            //Store zero in column if number is 
            //greater than 100
            temp2 = temp % 100;
            itoa(temp2, temp3, 10);
            currencyBuffer[i] = temp3;

            //Go back and add one to currency buffer
            temp = atoi(currencyBuffer[i-1].c_str());
            temp += 1;
            itoa(temp, temp3, 10);
            currencyBuffer[i - 1] = temp3;
        }

        i++;

        //Get next token
        tokenPtr = strtok(nullptr, ".");
    }
    NewLine();

    std::string tempBuffer;

    //Store entire worth of potions
    tempBuffer = "Platinum: ";
    tempBuffer += currencyBuffer[0];
    tempBuffer += "\nGold: ";
    tempBuffer += currencyBuffer[1];
    tempBuffer += "\nSilver: ";
    tempBuffer += currencyBuffer[2];
    tempBuffer += "\nCopper: ";
    tempBuffer += currencyBuffer[3];

    mCost = tempBuffer;
}
```

Comment: uhm... not sure here but, why 0? if it's 150S, it should be 1G50S, no? you need to look into division and remainders... this should help: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/9349/c-division-remainder-help note the last post which is very important...

Comment: That is definitely my bad.  It should be the modulus operator getting the remainder (i.e. if it were 105, the remainder would be 5 with one as a carry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
currencyBuffer[i - 1] = temp;
```

You're assigning an int (`temp`) to a string (`currencyBuffer[i-1]`), which causes garbage characters to be written. This is allowed, apparently:
([Why does C++ allow an integer to be assigned to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177704/why-does-c-allow-an-integer-to-be-assigned-to-a-string))
because ints can be converted implicitly to chars, and chars can be assigned to strings,.

You want to convert temp to a char using `itoa` or a similar function (you already did the opposite correctly, atoi, when you were getting the int from the string).

Since you're in C++, an easy way to do this is:

```
std::stringstream itos;
itos << temp;
currencyBuffer[i-1] = itos.c_str();
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I used itoa and now it works perfectly.  Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to fix the "temp2 = temp % 100;" line.  If a user enters 200, there is supposed to be a carry of two, but right now I just have it set up to do one carry regardless (i.e. if the number is larger than 100).

Comment: Yeah, because you have commands to "go back and add one to the currency buffer". :) You want to change the line `temp += 1;` to `temp += atoi(tokenPtr)/100;`

Comment: The `%` gets the remainder. You should have another variable, let's call it `quotient`, that gets the quotient: `quotient = temp / 100;`. Dividing an int by another gives you the quotient, so dividing e.g. 205 by 100 will give you 2. Then you say `temp += quotient;`. In the previous comment, instead of putting things in a separate variable called `quotient`, I just re-obtained the number using the `atoi` because I am that lazy.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is just me here (my C++ days go back about 13 years), and your teacher would be best suited to answer you this, but it feels like what you're doing/how you're doing it is very processor intensive. Technically, you would probably be better off splitting the whole string into an array of strings, and then using those to determine your final count:

```
std::string str = "I.have.a.dog";
//replace all DOTS with SPACES for next use
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
    if (str[i] == '.')
      str[i] = ' ';
}
std::istringstream stm(str) ;
string word ;
while( stm >> word ) // read white-space delimited tokens one by one 
{
   // put word into array
}
```

From there, you have an array, with the proper text/word, into an array, that you can use to do your calcs on... just a thought though... don't quote me on it ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is function I have created to parse your number. It has no problem with numbers larger than... Use it if you wish =)

```
unsigned long int str2cur(std::string cost)
{
    unsigned long int money = 0;
    //given that there are always 4 segments
    int end;
    do
    {
        end = cost.find('.', 0);
        money = money * 100 + atoi(cost.substr(0, end).c_str());
        cost.erase(0, end + 1);         
    }
    while (end != std::string::npos);
    return money;
}
```

Comment: Output of this function is total amount of money in the lowest denomination