# (C++) Initializing a string variable with a deferenced pointer pointing to an integer and it's printing something?

Tags: c++, pointers

I've been trying to get some head start on my programming diploma and decided to teach myself some C++ just to know what I'm getting into. So my situation is that I've initialized a string variable called thisIsAString by assigning it the value of a deferenced pointer pointing to an integer variable. I thought it wouldn't work since they're not really compatible variable types but it did gave me \350 when outputting the result to the console. I'm looking to understand what it actually means. This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
   string thisIsAString; 
   int randomVariable = 32; 

   int *ptrRandomVar = &randomVariable;
   *ptrRandomVar = 1000; 

   thisIsAString = *ptrRandomVar; 

   cout << thisIsAString << endl;
 }
```

So when I output this it gives me the result \350 and I don't have a clue what it means.

All help is appreciated :) ! 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's not supposed to mean anything, what you are doing it just wrong.

Comment: You are trying to assign an int to a std::string

Comment: This is the equivalent of sticking fish into your pillow and then being amazed that the pillow smells of fish when you go to sleep :-) Like Joachim Pileborg said above -- what you did does not make sense.

Comment: Yes I know it's wrong but I wanted to know what that \350 meant out of curiosity.

Comment: Since the compiler wasn't producing any error messages I decided to compile it just to see it what it would do.

Comment: The compiler didn't even give a warning? Then you should turn on more warnings! While some compiler warnings can be disregarded, some may actually indicate cases of undefined behavior. Fixing warnings is, in my mind, just as important as fixing compiler errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does C++ allow an integer to be assigned to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177704/why-does-c-allow-an-integer-to-be-assigned-to-a-string)

Comment: Confiture is clearly learning, he's asking why this is happening not whether its right or wrong, he knows he's wrong but he wants to know why its producing a result anyway? perhaps instead of telling him he's wrong and giving answers that are above the level that he's learning at we can actually find an appropriate answer?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg For fairness' sake it should be said that what we have here is an implicit conversion from `int` to `char`, which is a standard conversion (even though it causes a loss of precision), and doesn't get a warning by default, not even with `-W -Wall`. On GCC and Clang, you need to add `-Wconversion` explicitly to get a warning here. Not sure about other compilers.

Answer (score 6):

```
   thisIsAString = *ptrRandomVar;
```

is the key line. *ptrRandomVar has the value 1000 (in decimal). This is converted into a char using the standard conversion rules, which will truncate it to 232 (1000 in hex is 0x3e8, which truncated gives 0xe8 == 232). That gives you a string containing the character with the value 232.

When you print that character your standard library does not know how to print the character with the value 232, so it is writing it out in octal for you (I have no idea if this is standard), which gives you the character "\350" where 0350 is 232 in octal.

Comment: Your answer has been saved ! I'm going to do a bit of googling on that for sure. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

**;TLDR** 1000 = 0x3E8 -> char 0xE8 = 232 = \350 (octal)

This is what happens step by step:

- `*ptrRandomVar = 1000;` 1000 gets encoded as 0x3E8, meaning in memory you get `E8030000...` assuming you're using a little-endian platform.
- `thisIsAString = *ptrRandomVar;` Now you assign this int to your string. Your compiler does not complain ! You can initialize a string with a char (which is also a 1 byte integer type), and you can use an implicit numeric conversion from int to char. So your string is now size 1 and char has value 0xE8 (the rest got truncated)
- `cout << thisIsAString << endl;` You ask to ouput the string : with no other specific code, the output is standard ASCII encoding. However 0xE8 (=232) is out of standard ASCII scope (which stops at 127). So the default behaviour is to output its octal value, preceded by a backslash. And 232 (0xE8) gives you \350 in octal.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert integer to character string and then assigned it.