# Why does map<string, string> accept ints as values?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I've recently been jarred by this:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<string, string> strings;
    strings["key"] = 88;  // surprisingly compiles
    //map<string, string>::mapped_type s = 88;  // doesn't compile as expected

    cout << "Value under 'key': '" << strings["key"] << "'" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It prints 'X' which is 88 in ASCII.

Why does a string map accept ints as values? The documentation for map's `operator[]` says it returns `mapped_type&` which is `string&` in this case and it doesn't have an implicit conversion from `int`, does it?

Comment: Related: [Why does C++ allow an integer to be assigned to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1177704/335858).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is because, as you say, `operator[]` returns a `std::string&`, which defines an `operator= (char c)`. Your commented-out example does not call the assignment operator, it is [copy-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), which will try to call explicit constructors of the class, of which there are no applicable ones in `std::string`.

Answer (score 3):

To complete the picture, note that:

```
strings[88] = "key";
```

does not compile as there is no `std::string` constructor from `char`/`int`. For `char`, `std::string` only defines the assignment operator.