# Ambigous integer assignment to string c++

Tags: c++, g++, implicit-conversion, clang++, stdstring

So, while playing around with C++, I did this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  std::string s{"someThing"};

  std::cout << "  s is: " << s << '\n';

  s = 97;

  std::cout << "  s is: " << s << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

And when I compiled this with g++, **it compiled perfectly**, and on running its output is:

```
  s is: someThing
  s is: a
```

but my doubt is **why did this compiled correctly?**

Then I found this SO question which addresses this:

[Why does C++ allow an integer to be assigned to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177704/why-does-c-allow-an-integer-to-be-assigned-to-a-string)

Then I found this from the C++ [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D):

```
basic_string& operator=( CharT ch );
```

So, my main questions are:

- **Shouldn't `basic_string& operator=( CharT ch );` be [explicit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit)**? That is, why is `s = 97` allowed? `s` is a string, then why should an integer be assigned to it by implicit conversion?
- **Can this `s = 97` implicit conversion be avoided/stopped?**

And, some side questions: this code compiled perfectly with g++, but not with clang, which reported this error:

```
error: expected ';' at end of declaration
std::string s{"someThing"};
                     ^
```

So, why is g++ able to compile this and clang can't?

Edit: Thanks to Edgar Rokyan, now it compiles with clang++ with the `-std=c++11` option.

Edit: So, from answers of *Edgar Rokyan* and *MSalters*, `assignment operator can't be made explicit`, okay, **but why is assigning an integer to a string allowed**?

Comment: You say "compiles perfectly". Does that imply you do not even get warnings with strict configg, e.g. with `g++ -Wall` or even stricter?

Comment: @Yunnosch I added `-Wall` flag, still there was no warning

Comment: It compiles in clang too `-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` without any warning. BTW: 97 can be safely cast to char. When you change it to e.g. 970 then you get warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't `basic_string& operator=( CharT ch );` be explicit ? That is,
>   why is this : `s = 97` allowed? `s` is a string, then why should an
>   integer be assigned to it by implicit conversion?

From [explicit specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit):

> The explicit specifier specifies that a **constructor or conversion
>   function (since C++11)** doesn't allow implicit conversions or
>   copy-initialization. It may only appear within the decl-specifier-seq
>   of the declaration of such a function within its class definition.

So, you cannot make an assignment operator explicit.

> Can this `s = 97` implicit conversion be avoided/stopped?

Generally speaking, no, because it is perfectly legal for *std::string*. When you call:

```
basic_string& operator=( CharT ch );
```

with `97` then `97` which has a type of *int* is converted into `char` and *operator=* is performed.

> So, why is g++ enable to compile this and clang doesn't?

Most probably, you try to compile your program with *clang* without *C++11* support.

Comment: my bad, not enabling c++11 support while compiling this with clang, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't `basic_string& operator=( CharT ch )`; be `explicit` ?

It can't be, it's not a constructor or conversion function.

> Can this `s = 97` implicit conversion be avoided/stopped?

Not in your code, as it's well-defined C++.