# Extract first template parameter type from any object

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I had a templated object in C++ `Test<T>` and I wanted to find out what the T value is so that when I pass `Test<T>` as a template argument to `TestWrapper<Test<T>>`, I can declare a variable called `T extradata` in the object `TestWrapper` that is the same as `Test`'s T type.

How can I achieve this by only modifying TestWrapper (i.e. making no changes to Test struct) ? Additionally is it possible to modify it so that it will extract from any object that takes 1 template parameter e.g. `foo<T>`, `bar<T>`, rather then just `Test<T>`>?

Thanks in advance.

```
template<typename T>
struct Test {
     T value;
};


//template -> extract first type parameter from any object as T
struct TestWrapper {
     T extradata;
};

int main() {

     TestWrapper<Test<int>> temp;
     temp.extradata = 123; // temp.extradata is a int, deduced from Test<int>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use partial template specialization to do that.

```
template<typename T>
struct Test {
     T value;
};

template <typename T>
struct TestWrapper;

template <template <typename> typename Outer, typename T>
struct TestWrapper<Outer<T>> {
     T extradata;
};

int main() {
     TestWrapper<Test<int>> temp;
     temp.extradata = 123; // temp.extradata is a int, deduced from Test<int>
}
```

In this example we have not defined any default definition for `TestWrapper`, so it will fail to compile if you give something that does not match the specialization.

Comment: I like this answer. The specialization thing is not a issue since I only want types of that form. Weird, on MSVC I do not get a compile time error when I change Test<int> to Test<std::string> but keep extradata = 123.

Comment: Yeah, that's a bit wierd. You can get the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177704/why-does-c-allow-an-integer-to-be-assigned-to-a-string).

Answer (score 1):

You can

```
// primary template
template <typename T>
struct TestWrapper {
    T extradata; // declare extradata with type T
                 // how to declare it depends on your intent
};

// partial specialization
template <template <typename...> class C, typename T, typename... Args>
struct TestWrapper<C<T, Args...>> {
     T extradata; // T is the 1st template parameter of C here
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper class to extract the first parameter of the instantiated template, for example:

```
template<class>
struct Extract;

template<template<class...> class V, class First, class... Rest>
struct Extract<V<First, Rest...>> {
  using type = First;
};

template<class T>
struct TestWrapper {
  typename Extract<T>::type extradata;
};
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/KvYa3WE9M)